# Format NaN value with CustomJShover bokeh plot

Tags: bokeh

I would like not to show NaN values (made with numpy.nan) of the matrix in Bokeh backend. I tried using CustomJSHover but I wasn't able to do anything because I got errors also for a simple example.

**code:**

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import holoviews as hv
import geoviews as gv 
hv.extension('bokeh','matplotlib') 
import cartopy.crs as crs
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJSHover

x,y = np.mgrid[-50:51, -50:51] * 0.1
r = 0.5*np.sin(np.pi  +3*x**2+y**2)+0.5
r[r<0.5]=np.nan
coords=np.arange(0,101)
custom=CustomJSHover(code="""
                     return value + " tot"
                     """)

tooltips=[
  ("value","@image{1.1}"),   # GIVES RIGHT VALUE BUT WITH NaNs (0.1..0.6.. etc)
  ("value","@image{custom}") # GIVES some strange 0th, 1st, ... or NaN
]

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips, formatters={'image' : custom})

ds = xr.Dataset({'R': (['x', 'y'],r)},coords={'x': (['x'], coords),'y': (['y'], coords)})
ensemble = gv.Image(ds, kdims=['x', 'y'],vdims=[ 'R']).opts(tools=[hover])
ensemble
```

I would like the `NaN` values are not being shown in {2.1} format and `NaN` values are white, so that they are not shown at all in the hover.

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: for a float64 (0.68) for example  I got 0th (I don't know what it is) , for NaN I got Nan as well

Comment: You can only have one custom formatter per field, so your `CustomJSHover` will have to handle all the cases, i.e. it will need to have an `if isnan(...)` check that does one thing for nans and something else for non-nans

Comment: I did not understand how to check, because if I do just the simple operation in the 'code' part above , it gives me back 0th,1th...etc

Comment: It's not really possible to speculate from the tiny snippet above. It's always best to provide a *complete* minimal reproducer, that others can run and investigate directly in order to help.

Comment: you are right sorry. Now I updated the code so you can visualize the image and see what I mean. Thanks